# Scheduled termination of nomad job

Tags: nomad

I'm looking for analogue of `nomad stop <job>` command which I can schedule from the job itself. Is there such a thing in Nomad? I failed to find anything which can do it. It looks like Nomad fundamentally only starting jobs, but stopping them is not something which can be specified in the definition.

The only idea I have is to have two jobs, one to start and another is to stop. The 'stop' one will use command line to stop the other one. Is that the right way? Wondering how everyone else is doing this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If your process finishes/exits the job will be stoped and can remain that way depending on how configure restart stanza. Why do you need something external to have control over your job?

Comment: @IlyaKisil I want the service to be down for an 1h every day/week/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just have your job exit with code 0, jobs don't need to run forever. Nomad will then mark the job as "complete" and you're done.

If the job itself can't control its own exit then yes, you might need to try and set up some external job that can make api calls to stop the task, but I'd recommend trying to just have the job exit when it has completed its task.

Answer (score 0):

Nomad have different [schedulers](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/schedulers#schedulers) for different type of jobs.

For you requirement, you can use [Nomad Batch job](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/schedulers#batch).

The default job type is [service](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/schedulers#service) so if you don't mention any job type it will run as a [service](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/schedulers#service) job which is expected to not exit unless stopped explicitly. You can mention the job type in the Nomad job file as follows:

```
job "sample" {
  type = "batch"
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am typically running my command prefixed with `timeout` linux command.

Running a separate job wothin the same job group to execute nomad job stop ${NOMAD_JOB_NAME} is certainly a way I would do. You would need to export a proper nomad token for the job.